# Affine transformation that sends a conic to itself but does not preserve the focci or the axes

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, transformation, conic-sections, affine-geometry

So I'm trying to find an affine transformation that sends a conic to itself but does not preserve the foci or the axes. I don't know if this can be done. I'm pretty sure that if it is possible then I have to do a sort of "conjugation" of transformations. But nothing I've tried seems to work.

This is sort of what I mean http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/wws/cabripages/klein/affinesymmetry.html

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If the conic is mapped to itself the foci and the axis stay the same.

Comment: Well that's what I thought, but I think the conic is not really mapped to itself, I just have to map it in a way that looks the same, that way the new conic will have different focci and the like.

Comment: then what is the meaning of "an affine transformation that sends a conic to itself"?

Comment: what I just said: the conic looks exactly the same, so the function has to send every point on the conic to exactly the same place at the end, but in the middle you do something (like rotating, dilating, etc) that results in the original foci and axes to end up somewhere else.

Comment: The foci and axis are determined by the support of the conic. If an affine map sends a conic to itself, the foci and axis fall in the same place.

Comment: Just to be clear: if there is an ellipse on the euclidean plane, we can find its foci and axis by straightedge and compass.

Comment: So: same ellipse, same foci and axis.

Comment: If it can't be done, then I need a proof.

Comment: C'mon folks, it's pretty obvious what's being asked here. The link makes that quite clear as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\lambda>0$ and $\lambda\neq 1$. The transformation $$(x,y)\mapsto(\lambda x, \lambda^{-1} y)$$ maps the hyperbola $xy=1$ to itself. It does not fix the foci or the symmetry axes. For any angle $\varphi$ that is not a multiple of $\pi$ the transformation $$(x, y)\mapsto(\cos(\varphi) x -\lambda \sin(\varphi) y, \lambda^{-1} \sin(\varphi) x+\cos(\varphi)y)$$ maps the ellipse $x^2+\lambda^2 y^2=1$ to itself but again it does not fix its foci or symmetry axes. The transformation $$(x,y)\mapsto (x+\lambda, y+2\lambda x+\lambda^2)$$ maps the parabola $y=x^2$ to itself but...

Comment: One question, how can I prove this transformations are in fact affine?

Comment: @Antry Affine is linear plus a translation. All transformations above (for fixed $\lambda$ and $\varphi$) are of that form.

Comment: Ok. Just one more thing, I can see why this works with the hyperbola and the parabola, but I don't see how the formula for the ellipse works.

Answer (score 3):

If a conic is given by the points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that:
$$ ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f = 0 \tag{1}$$
then the foci and axis of the conic depend on $(a,b,c,d,e,f)\in\mathbb{P}^5(\mathbb{R})$. If a conic is mapped to itself by an affine map, then its equation $(1)$ stays the same, so the foci and axis stay the same, too.

If that wasn't convincing enough, again: if there is an ellipse/parabola/hyperbola on the euclidean plane, you can find its foci and axis by straightedge and compass. So same conic, same foci and axis.

Comment: http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/wws/cabripages/klein/affinesymmetry.html

Comment: That says that two points on a conic can be exchanged by an affine map that sends a conic to itself. It doesn't mention foci or axis.

Comment: Yes it does: "The theorem shows that this can be transformed to any point
on the same conic. Thus, there is no affine characterization of the vertex. A similar
argument shows that the major axis of an ellipse, and the transverse axis of a hyperbola
are not affine concepts. It also confirms that the foci do not have affine descriptions,
since they lie on these axes."

Comment: The foci are not points on the conic.

Comment: That just says that if an affine map $\varphi$ maps the conic $\Gamma_1$ into $\Gamma_2$, then it is not true that the foci of $\Gamma_2$ are given by $\varphi$ applied to the foci of $\Gamma_1$. Again, it is pretty trivial by considering ellipses on the euclidean plain.

Comment: So suppose I map a conic to another one, then the foci of the first are not mapped to the focci of the second, now suppose I map the second one to a third one and from this third one I map to the first one. ¿Then what happens with the foci?

Comment: The question seems to be about the subgroup of affine transformations that fix a given conic, not about the equation of the conic.

Comment: Even if the focii and axis are the same, it doesn't mean they are fixed by the transformation.